# Upstart service not starting when a service it depends on starts

Tags: upstart, services

I have a service called service C. It has the following start and stop conditions:

```
start on ( started A and started B)
stop on (stopping A or stopping B)
```

When I manually stop A, C stops. However, When I start A, C doesn't start unless I stopped and started B as well.

I want C to run whenever A and B are both running, and the above conditions don't achieve that. Any ideas on what the start conditions should look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your start stanza to 'or' like so:

`start on ( started A or started B )`

Then add a pre-start script that checks whether both services are running, and abort the start if they aren't. Something like:

```
pre-start script
  if [ -z `status A | grep running` ] || [ -z `status B | grep running` ]; then
    stop ; exit 0
  fi
end script
```

See the 'pre-start' section of the [cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). There's probably a better way to check if a service is running, but this works for me. Adapt to suit your needs.